# Maven including old SNAPSHOT when building

Tags: java, macos, maven, snapshot

I have switched from the 13.4.20-SNAPSHOT to developing the 14.1.18-SNAPSHOT.  With this change, I have altered some of the packages.  Now instead of a commons path, they are using a libraries path.  When compiling (using mvn verify -U) I notice two things:
1 - The 13.4.20-SNAPSHOT versions are being loaded in addition to the 14.1.18-SNAPSHOT versions
2 - There is a whole list of 'incompatible types' errors because the packages have changed.

I think somehow the new code is trying to call the old code - so a libraries is being sent instead of a commons.

Why is the old SNAPSHOT being included?  I have searched my entire computer, and have found no reference to the old SNAPSHOT.

Here is the Output:

```
Command: mvn verify -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Program 14.1.18-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/bar/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/bar/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1002 B at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (999 B at 19.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/help/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/help/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (997 B at 19.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared-resources/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared-resources/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (791 B at 15.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/bar/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/bar/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1002 B at 19.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://<<nexus ip>>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/shared/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (999 B at 19.9 KB/sec)

(Skipped other downloads)

sources/14.1.18-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (789 B at 10.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.1:create (default) @ Program ---
[INFO] Checking for local modifications: skipped.
[INFO] Updating project files from SCM: skipped.
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program && git rev-parse --verify HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: a44fed602cb210fd0539e2c5f8ab259df3bcf224 at timestamp: 1385134818593
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program && git rev-parse --verify HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generateDependenciesProgram) @ Program ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:

generateFiles:

initproperties:

gslgen:
     [exec] gslgen M: Processing src/main/resources/gslgen/gui.xml with src/main/resources/gslgen/modules.gsl...
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Program ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 78 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Program ---
[INFO] Compiling 84 source files to /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program/src/main/java/com/foo/Program/webflow/MasterFormAction.java:[845,49] error: incompatible types
[ERROR]   required: com.foo.underwriting.libraries.address.Address
  found:    com.foo.underwriting.commons.address.Address
/Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program/src/main/java/com/foo/Program/webflow/MasterFormAction.java:[871,69] error: method filterScrubbedAddresses in interface ValuationService cannot be applied to gProgramen types;
[ERROR]   required: ArrayList<com.foo.underwriting.commons.address.ScrubbedAddress>,MasterWidget
  found: ArrayList<com.foo.underwriting.libraries.address.ScrubbedAddress>,MasterWidget
  reason: actual argument ArrayList<com.foo.underwriting.libraries.address.ScrubbedAddress> cannot be converted to ArrayList<com.foo.underwriting.commons.address.ScrubbedAddress> by method invocation conversion
/Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program/src/main/java/com/foo/Program/webflow/MasterFormAction.java:[881,67] error: incompatible types
[ERROR]   required: com.foo.underwriting.libraries.address.ScrubbedAddress
  found:    com.foo.underwriting.commons.address.ScrubbedAddress
/Users/Bob/dev/apps/Program/src/main/java/com/foo/Program/webflow/MasterFormAction.java:[892,45] error: method syncScrubbbedAddressAndStructure in interface ValuationService cannot be applied to gProgramen types;
(And many more incompatible errors)
```

EDIT

The mvn Dependency Tree:

```
Command: mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Program 14.1.18-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ Program ---
[INFO] com.foo:Program:war:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.1_02:compile
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.1_02:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.metaparadigm:json-rpc:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.foo:bar-test-utils:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:logback-utils:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:logging:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:caching:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:email:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:app-config:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:air-webservices:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.2.2.v20101205:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.2.2.v20101205:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.2.2.v20101205:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.2.2.v20101205:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.2.2.v20101205:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jra:jra:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:xml-utils:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:credentials:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:address:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sourceforge.jgeocoder:jgeocoder:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- berkeleydb:je:jar:3.2.44:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.0.73:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:passport:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:evaluator:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.bing.underwriting.libraries:item-hierarchy-parser:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:shared-resources:war:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:bar:jar:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.foo:shared:jar:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:address:jar:1.0.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:address-scrubber:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.bing.underwriting.commons:credentials:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:address-parser:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:air-webservices:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:caching:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:evaluator:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.bing.underwriting.commons:email:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:qas-webservices:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:security:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:util:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:xml-utils:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.iso:location:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:passport:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:item-hierarchy-parser:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.bing.underwriting.commons:logback-utils:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.bing.underwriting.commons:dashboard:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- diana.ms.mff.cuni.cz:javaGeom:jar:0.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zefer:pd4ml:jar:380fx8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.steadystate:ss_css2:jar:0.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc-portlet:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:bar-resources:war:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:help:jar:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:help-resources:war:14.1.18-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.0-GA:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.724s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 22 09:36:53 MST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/410M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: do a `mvn clean` first. it might be that you still have the old .classes

Comment: Thanks - I did.  The full log (-X) shows that it cannot find the old snapshot on my current machine, so it goes to the main nexus repository.

Comment: [DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.foo:shared:13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/bob/.m2/repository)
    [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://<nexusIP>/nexus/content/groups/public as bob
    Downloading: http://<nexusIP>/nexus/content/groups/public/com/bar/shared/13.4.20-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
999/999 B

Comment: Can you reduce this to the *minimal*, complete amount needed for anyone to reproduce this?

Comment: I think something is still pulling the old dependency. Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and see who is pulling the old 13.4.20

Comment: Flexo - True this is more of a core dump.

Comment: @Hilkus Good idea, but no mention of 13.4.20

Answer (score 0):

The target directory had some old builds in it.  By clearing the directory I was able to remove the error.  I am still getting old snapshots, but it is not interfering anymore.